# django <a href='...'> redirected to account/login by chrome

Tags: html, django, google-chrome

Can someone explain what is happening?  The following href works on firefox but gets redirected inside Chrome.   Any my visualization view is not displayed.

### BEHAVIOR

I am at the top page of myapp... drawn via mysite.views.page showing templates/myapp/home.html (extends a navigation set of buttons via templates/myapp/base.html).

When I hover over the button it displays

```
127.0.0.1:8000/vis/myapp/assets.default
```

When I click on it I get different behavior

Firefox - invokes the view and visualization occurs correctly.

```
myapp.views.visualization module
```

On Chrome, it displays the login page... url of page is

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=vis/myapp/assets.default
```

What is ?next= 
I have confimed that views.visualization() is not called. 
I don't see any GET posting in the logs?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is the code... let me know if you need to see other things.

### templates/myapp/base.html

```
{% block app_nav_list %}

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="/vis/myapp/assets.default">Assets</a></li>
<li>...</li>
...    
<li class="dropdown">
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">My<br>Settings<b class="caret"></b></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

### mysite.views.page()

```
def page(request, hname = 'index'):
    pagePath = hname.strip().split('.')
    pgName = '/'.join(pagePath)
    return render_to_response(pgName+'.html')
```

### myapp/urls.py

```
from mysite.urls import urlpatterns

urlpatterns += patterns('',
   url(r'^vis/myapp/(?P<visualName>.*)', 'myapp.views.visualization'),
   url(r'^actions/myapp/(?P<actionName>.*)', 'myapp.views.actions'),
)
```

### mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html')),
   # Serve pages per each app using views.pages (relative to templates)
   # calls views.pages(request, pagename=xx, apptops=x)
   url(r'^page/(?P<hname>.*)', 'mysite.views.page'),
)
# Import APP URLS
import myapp.urls
#
# Admin URLS
#
# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),   
admin_urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # login/registration auth urls
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'mysite.views.login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/auth/$', 'mysite.views.auth_view'),
    url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$', 'mysite.views.loggedin'),
    url(r'^accounts/invalid/$', 'mysite.views.invalid_login'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'mysite.views.login_register'),
    url(r'^actions/register/$', 'mysite.views.login_register_action'),
    url(r'^accounts/register_success/$', 'mysite.views.login_register_success'),
)
urlpatterns += admin_urlpatterns
```

Comment: looks like you are not logged in while accessing the url in chrome.

Comment: duhhhh!   Thanks!   We're working on the admin/sessions sections.... so pages disabled the @login_required....  Thanks again.